# How to get the coordinates(X,Y) of the pattern lock component in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to get the coordinates of X and Y of the pattern lock component. The code that i'm using to create the Pattern Lock component is from aritraroy/PatternLockView which can be found on Github. Firstly, i set the root view on a view variable like this:

[image]

and then i set the `OnTouchListener` on root view.
Finally i create the the `PatterLockViewListener`:

```
final PatternLockViewListener mPatternLockViewListener = new PatternLockViewListener() {

    //do whatever

}
```

What i want is by clicking the `PatternLock` component to get the coordinates(X,Y) in correlation to the root view. Instead i get the coordinates in all other components except from the `PatternLock` (by clicking the `PatternLock` component the `OnTouchListener` doesnt trigger and as a result, the code is not working/running)

Answer (score 2):

The solution that finally worked for me after searching for 3, 4 days is this:

```
public class Pattern extends AppCompatActivity
{

    PatternLockView pattern_lock;

    //x,y coordinates for when the finger touches the screen



    //x,y coordinates for when the finger moves around the screen


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {

        pattern_lock = (PatternLockView)findViewById(R.id.pattern_screen);

        pattern_lock.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {

                switch (event.getAction())
                {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                         //code
                        return Pattern.super.onTouchEvent(event);
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                         //code
                        return Pattern.super.onTouchEvent(event);
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                         //code
                        return Pattern.super.onTouchEvent(event);
                }

                return true;
             }

        });

    }

}
```

I'm not really sure why to return that (return Pattern.super.onTouchEvent(event);) and not true as most posts say about onTouch.